# php fun codeing

Tags: php

hey I make a simple php table using nested for loop ... and it will be like this...

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
```

but the problem is , i can not print this value using a loop inside the column .. so what will be the solution ??? please

**my code :**

```
echo "<table border=1>\n";
for($row=1;$row<=3;$row++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($col=1;$col<=5;$col++)
    {
        echo "<td>";
        echo "MY PROBLEM HERE...I cant print column numbers \n";
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table> \n";
```

Comment: Why you can't print column  number?


`echo $col;`

Comment: same question why can't you print column number? what are trying to print?

Comment: echo $col + $row * 5 ?

Comment: because after every row his columns will repeat(1 to 5) instead of incrementing.. he will need a variable which will keep a track of this..

Comment: I think $row and $col already contains all the information he needs

Comment: Yep, I deleted my comment. Should be `$row*5 + $col` where `$row` starts from `0`, not from `1`. Or `($row - 1)*5 + $col` if `$row` starts from `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save several loops:

```
$rows = 3;
$cols = 5;

$table = '<table border="1">';

for($i=1;$i<=$rows;$i++){
    $table .= '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', range($cols*$i-$cols+1,$cols*$i)).'</td></tr>';
}

$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "<table border=1>\n";
for($row=1;$row<=3;$row++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($col=1;$col<=5;$col++)
    {
        echo "<td>";
        //echo "MY PROBLEM HERE...I cant print column numbers \n";
        echo $col + ($row - 1) * 5;
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table> \n";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not `$col + $row * 5`  it has to be `$row - 1`

```
<?php
echo "<table border=1>\n";
for($row=1;$row<=3;$row++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for($col=1;$col<=5;$col++)
    {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $col + ($row-1) * 5;
        echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table> \n";

?>
```